# Updating constrains of NIB View

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constants, nib

I am loading View to VC from NIB with code below

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self createProfileHeaderViewNib];
}


- (void)createProfileHeaderViewNib
{
    ProfileHeaderView *profileHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    profileHeaderView.frame = self.profileHeaderView.frame;
    self.profileHeaderView = profileHeaderView;
    self.profileHeaderView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.profileHeaderView];
}
```

And it works good.
Problem is appears then I change iPhone 5 to 6, or otherwise.

I created this View for iPhone 5. If I change device to iPhone 6 this view did not layout. But If I create it View for iPhone 6 I will have the same problem for iPhone 5.

The same situations is I change VIewControllers size to Freeform or to Inherited

I load view with its settled  constrains from NIB. How can I update contains/view size after I get NIB using 'loadNibNamed:'?

Comment: You can create IBOutlets for your constraints and modify them or why not simply add the `ProfileHeaderView` to your nib file?

Comment: Paulw11, how can I add one nib file to another?

Comment: You can add a UIView to your outer nib, set its custom class and then load the nib in the initializer for the custom class, however your problem may be as simple as not implementing the sub view layout methods in your UIView subclass

Comment: Paulw11, can you post some code please?

Comment: See here - http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/282

Comment: Paulw11, Can you please check why it not working for me? I tried all from this tutorial but did not get View from NIB https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0mwsn3ik8y62nlq/AAB5sE72LzefY-trmXWQ1dZYa?dl=0